# Customizing addressbook in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am customizing addressbook in NetSuite. For this, I have added one new script file in the 'Custom Address entry form'. Here everything is working fine. Now whenever I am trying to save record using save button on any entity form, I am getting an exception. I have written some code on save button. I have debugged the code then I found that

```
'var address1 = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr1');'
```

nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue not able to fetch addr1 from addressbook.

Plz help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Address book is actually subrecord of the line item in NetSuite. You can use below code to access addressbook details

```
//grab subrecord
nlapiSelectLineItem('addressbook', 2);
var subrecord = nlapiViewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
//grab fields from subrecord
var country = subrecord.getFieldValue('country');
var addr1 = subrecord.getFieldValue('addr1');
```

OR

```
//grab subrecord
var subrecord = nlapiViewLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress', 1);

//grab fields from subrecord
var country = subrecord.getFieldValue('country');
var addr1 = subrecord.getFieldValue('addr1');
```

If you want to edit the subrecord details, I recommend the below syntax to grab subrecord instead. Above syntax is for view purpose only

```
nlapiSelectLineItem('addressbook', 2);
var subrecord = nlapiEditCurrentLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
subrecord.setFieldValue('addr1', 'Your addr1');
subrecord.commit();
nlapiCommitLineItem('addressbook');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have tried your both code. but for 'addressbookaddress' I am getting '"addressbookaddress" is not a valid internal id.' 
Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, but it helped me to find my way, the following code worked for me

```
var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
var addrtext = record.getLineItemValue('addressbook','addrtext',1);
```